# sql query with date intevals

Tags: sql

Hi I need help to create a query that return a result based on date interval but I can't get it to work correctly.

I would like to achieve a result giving me the records with a date that are within a historic time span:

```
day -1 to -7   */from yesterday and -7 days */      
day -8 to -14  */the date is between -8 and -14 days from today
```

For the first interval I use this where clause:

```
...
where `invoiceExpDate` >= date_add(now(), INTERVAL - 7 DAY)
```

how can I modify this to NOT give me the records for today??

For the second interval I use:

```
...
where datediff(invoiceExpDate,now())<= 14 
AND datediff(invoiceExpDate,now())> 7 
AND  `invoiceExpDate` > now()
```

I can't get them to work. CAn you help me with the correct where clause to return what I want?

Thanks

Comment: What DBMS? Date functions are notorious for their differences between platforms.

Comment: Your query conditions don't make sense (completely).  You are looking for things that are x days old range, but then in your second interval are looking for invoice exp date > now().  That would always return an empty set... All that have an old expiration date that are greater than now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can combine date_add() and BETWEEN

For your first clause

```
...
WHERE `invoiceExpDate` BETWEEN 
    date_add(now(), INTERVAL - 7 DAY) AND 
    date_add(now(), INTERVAL - 1 DAY)
```

Similar pattern for the second.

Comment: Yes It worked. So easy when you know how to do it :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> LogDate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE()) AND 
>                     DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())